# Display overlay div and push the other (text, image) element on a post

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, position

I want to put a blockquote on a center of a post and push the other text to top, right, left and bottom Like the image bellow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dleAF.jpg

I am using CSS like this but the quote only overlay and cover up the other element.

```
blockquote {
   position:absolute;
   width:75px;
   height:75px;
   border-radius:50%;
   background-color:#000;
   color:#fff;
   left:45%;
   top:#45%
}
```

Anybody know how to resolve the problem? Should I use Jquery?
Really appreciate for any idea.

Regards

Comment: Have a look at [Getting started with CSS Shapes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/)

Comment: Thanks, @Azis. Read and noted. Look like will be my solution.

Comment: I know it isnt exactly what you're looking for (since theyre fixed blocks), but [this question can be interesting for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392042/advanced-css-tricks-how-to-span-an-image-over-multiple-columns-in-a-css3-site-l)

Comment: Plus I recommend you to avoid tinypic since their links automaticaly change for **userlanguage**.tinypic.com/6nywdi.jpg and do not work for people outside of your country. For this purpose I recommend [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/)

Comment: @freestock.tk : look like promising, but they can not push the other element. Will check closer then. Thank you. Just edit and use imgur.com